# Spring Boot Multi Module Application - How to create one deployable single jar file to execute using maven clean install command

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure, maven

Please help me in creating 1 jar file includes all the modules / class files in Spring Boot Multi Module Project. Using Maven and build tool and need to create Single Jar file and executable as Spring boot project.
Tried using the Maven Assembly but it does not includes the Modules Jar file into Parent's Project when Jar is created

Need help with sample POM files and Modules POM file

Comment: Sorry, I do not really understand. If you declare other modules are `<dependencies>` in the `pom.xml`, they should be included automatically.

Comment: Have you looked at the spring boot documentation?

Comment: I did. When the Parent POM have the <package>pom</package>                          
        and                                                                                                         
     <modules>
        <module>module-one</module>
        <module>module-two</module>
    </modules>. Then the mvn clean install DOES NOT create the JAR file

Comment: Can you show the `pom.xml` files? Are the modules dependent on each other? Did you check the `target` directory of the child modules for the JARs as well?